# problem in creating ROS Workspace

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all...

I've installed Ubuntu 16 Xenial and also ROS Kinetic.
I tried to run simulation with Gazebo.
when I executed `catkin_make` in creating ROS workspace, I found this following error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "driver_base" with
any of the following names:
  driver_baseConfig.cmake
  driver_base-config.cmake
```

and this one:

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/seano/simulation/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/seano/simulation/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:290: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

any idea..??

thanks..

Seano

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248803/problem-in-creating-ros-workspace/) by [Seano](https://answers.ros.org/users/25807/seano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error basically tells you that you don't have the `driver_base` package on your system. Whatever you are trying to `catkin_make` needs that package, and so Catkin (really CMake) can't continue.

Looking at [wiki/driver_base](http://wiki.ros.org/driver_base), it looks like that package hasn't been released into Kinetic. And based on the package's description, it looks like that may not happen ever:

> A framework for writing drivers that helps with runtime reconfiguration, diagnostics and self-test. This package is deprecated.

> Maintainer status: end-of-life (Will be released only as long as required for PR2 drivers (hokuyo_node, wge100_driver))

What package are you trying to build?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0